# CSS Table: Can ANY html structure be formatted as a table through CSS?

Tags: css, width, css-tables

With display:table it is relatively easy to make table-like structures where all cells have equal space. However, when the html gets more complex (more nested), I cannot get it to work. Is this because there are some constrictions in how the html is structured in order to format them as a table?

For example, consider the following html. Is it possible to format it so that all cells have the same width? (the css is the closest I've been able to write)

https://jsfiddle.net/9eq5m2o0/6/

(check that at jsfiddle, the snippet here goes weird due to the limited width)

```css
.general {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 2px 1px;
}

.main_node {
display:table-row;
}

.node {
display:table-cell;
}

.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {
  float:left;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <div class="main_node">
    <div class="node">
      <div class="col1">col1</div>
      <div class="col2">hofgghla</div>
      <div class="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="node">
      <div class="col1">col1</div>
      <div class="col2">holaahola</div>
      <div class="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="node">
      <div class="col1">col1</div>
      <div class="col2">holahola</div>
      <div class="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="node">
      <div class="col1">col1</div>
      <div class="col2">holaholholaholaahola</div>
      <div class="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_node">
    <div class="node">
      <div class="col1">col1</div>
      <div class="col2">hola</div>
      <div class="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="node">
      <div class="col1">col1</div>
      <div class="col2">holaholaholaholaholahola</div>
      <div class="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="node">
      <div class="col1">col1</div>
      <div class="col2">holahola</div>
      <div class="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="node">
      <div class="col1">col1</div>
      <div class="col2">holaholahola</div>
      <div class="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can align all columns without specifying any width as follows:

```css
.aligned-columns {
  float: left;
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 2px 1px;
}
.node {
  display: table-row;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3 {
  padding:2px;
  margin:2px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="aligned-columns">
  <div class="node">
    <div class="col1">col1</div>
    <div class="col2">hola</div>
    <div class="col3">col3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <div class="col1">col100</div>
    <div class="col2">holaholaholahola</div>
    <div class="col3">col35</div>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <div class="col1">col101</div>
    <div class="col2">holahola</div>
    <div class="col3">col36</div>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <div class="col1">col102</div>
    <div class="col2">holaholahola</div>
    <div class="col3">col37</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its better to add a class on parent and style with that otherwise generic styles will be applied on all divs in your page.

Comment: But I cannot change the div structure, I will edit the question to extend the structure but bottom-line message, I want to know if I can do something with this html structure rather than write a constant presumed length

Comment: I've also edited my question, hope it's clearer what I'm looking for. I'll try to adapt your answer there now

Comment: @Gerard I've added one variant, May be it will helpful for you.

Comment: Yes, this is it, but doesn't work for me because my html structure is a little bit more complex. I've updated the question with similar html that I cannot get it to work, maybe you can take a look ...

Comment: @Gerard All `.node` elements should be inside single parent Otherwise Its  not possible to align them with pure css. https://jsfiddle.net/9eq5m2o0/7/

Comment: do you have any link where this is stated somehow? I agree with you, but I'd like to see some web page highlighting this limitation

Comment: @Gerard I don't have any links for this, I've shared with you just my experience and understanding.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot, I've had to stick with my width-fixed divs then since I don't want to change the html structure, it makes sense from a data organization perspective